# Can't catch data sent from JSP using ajax to servlet in Java EE

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

```
$('#fillUpdateOwnerButton').on('click', function () {
                var email = $('#eMailUpdateOwner').val();
                console.log(email);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "updateBusOwnerDetailsServlet",
                    data: {"emailForSearch": email},
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
```

above is the code between the `<Script>` tag, that console.log() also prints nothing and below I mention how I try to get data by Servlet, but this is not working, it prints null,

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("emailForSearch"));
```

Comment: I copied your client-side code to an `index.jsp` file and completed it with appropriate surrounding HTML, and I copied your line of Java code to an `updateBusOwnerDetailsServlet.jsp` file placed inside the `<% ... %>` JSP scriptlet tags. I also had to create a `WEB-INF/web.xml` deployment descriptor file to map the URL pattern `/updateBusOwnerDetailsServlet` to the `/updateBusOwnerDetailsServlet.jsp` file. After doing all of the above, everything worked perfectly. Hence, the code you've posted is perfect, and the problem on your end must be related to the surrounding server setup.

Comment: If you provide more information about your server setup, particularly the JSP file names and paths you have in your webapp, and what you're doing with your `web.xml` descriptor, then we can look into this further.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ajax call with this :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#fillUpdateOwnerButton').on('click', function () {
        var email = $('#eMailUpdateOwner').val();
        console.log(email);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "updateBusOwnerDetailsServlet",
            data: {"emailForSearch": email},
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You have to load ajax in page on document ready . Checked from my end working fine. Let me know for any issues

Answer (score 0):

i think **fillUpdateOwnerButton** this is your button's id if this is so

try to change

$('#fillUpdateOwnerButton').on('click', function () {}

in this replace  **$('#fillUpdateOwnerButton')** to **$('#document')**
or immediate parent container's id of your button

since you have not pasted your code I can help you out till here

try this or pase full code